# SSLv2Hello cannot be enabled

Tags: java, web-services, ssl

I've been  working on a Java webservice client. It works fine for everybody except for one customer who has this error:

```
class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException :
SSLv2Hello cannot be enabled unless at least one other supported version is also enabled
```

I can't reproduce the error. We're using the same server trying to test it, and it works fine for me and all of my collegues. The only thing different that we're using our certificate and the user is using his.
Tried *System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3");* 
Then I got this:

```
class javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException :
Failed to access the WSDL at: https:something:someport/something/something?wsdl. It failed with: 
    No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate).
```

The client is using:
 
JVM: 1.8.0_40 
Operating System: Windows 7

I'm clueless how can i solve this, or what path to take to further explore the problem.

Answer (score 1):

SSLv2Hello cannot come alone, it needs another protocol to be allowed (SSLv3, TLS,..)

Your code seems to work as you can test it almost anywhere with good results. It's then an environment problem on the faulty tester, by configuration or JDK version.

Check environment variables, java.security file (particularly jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms key which can be empty for testing) , and deployment.properties file if any.
It's often a good idea to dump all environment properties during the client or server startup.

Comment: Got the  user's java.security file.  i could not reproduce the error with that file either. :(

Comment: This error message happens (in theory) when there is only one protocol (SSLv2Hello) allowed, either by configuration or by setting it in the Java code. By configuration, this means in java.security file as said in my answer, or by an environment variable ( https.protocols  , jdk.tls.client.protocols ) as explained in the JSSE reference documentation. You should dump all properties when starting your client then we see if it's an environment setting. Maybe should you upgrade to Java 8u141 minimum because this one corrects some bugs.

Comment: When decompiling the classes, the reason becomes obvious. The client not only locally checks the Supported Protocols list (in two places!) but it also checks that it has a Cipher Suite that can be used with the any of the Protocols that are currently "enabled". Since Java usually (or, at least the one I have) ships with 40-something suites, which are all TLS, you need at least TLSv1 to go with the SSLv2Hello, otherwise the internal classes think none of the available Suites will fit the protocol anyway and gives up.

Comment: PS: It's very messy inside and looks like it was written by thousands of people who never spoke to each other and there was no control about how things are done ;)
The quality of code inside Java is shocking.
Also their decisions. There's a reason Java is on the decline